# Multiple values of a parameter in HTTP request

Tags: php, laravel, api, http

I am working with an external API in Laravel - where I have to make the below request.

There is a parameter product which is to be repeated for each of the product - however when the below request is sent only the last value of the product is recognized at the endpoint.

```
$action = Http::get('https://http.cc/api/call.xml', [
                'authid' => env('API_USER'),
                'api-key' => env('API_KEY'),
                'product' => 'Some Value',
                'product' => 'Some Value',
                'customer' => 1,
            ]);
```

I have also tried the following but failed:

```
'product[]' => 'Some Value',
'product[]' => 'Some Value',
```

```
'product' => ['Some Value', 'Some Value']
```

Can anyone help with the solution here.

API: https://manage.logicboxes.com/kb/answer/776 (you can refer to ns parameter)

Comment: 'product' => ['Some Value', 'Some Value']?

Comment: Correct, that's what I had tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the link. If you look at the `ns` parameter, it has a link called `"Array of Strings"`. You can click it for an explanation. It gives an example:

```
Example: ?variable=1&variable=2&variable=3&variable=4
```

Now I can understand your problem. Laravel doesn't support multiple variables with the same name. You can however still use it, but you have to build your own query string. Like so:

```
// start by building a normal query string
$query = http_build_query([
                           'authid'   => env('API_USER'),
                           'api-key'  => env('API_KEY'),
                           'customer' => 1,
                          ]);
// then add your products
foreach ($products as $product) {
   $query .= '&product=' . urlencode($product);
}
// finally build the url yourself
$action = Http::get('https://http.cc/api/call.xml?' . $query);
```

see: [http_build_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) and [urlencode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).